# Remove Processing from windows PC

Tags: processing

How can I completely remove Processing from Windows 7 ? I have downloaded the 2.2.1 for windows 64 and then added javascript mode . Now Processing starts in javascript but the mode button is gone and Processing shows lots of errors in red at the bottom of the window. Even when I try to close it, it freezes. The play, stop , new, save and export buttons are missing too.
How can I remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I never seem to have experienced these problems in Processing 2.2.1.

Anyways, as a first step, try removing JavaScript mode, and reinstalling it. To remove it, go to Documents>Processing>modes, and delete the Javascript folder that you see there.

In case this doesn't work, try reinstalling Processing by removing it, and then downloading it again. 
To remove Processing completely, delete the Processing folder in the Documents folder. Go to File>Preferences and click on the file path at the bottom. Close Processing, go up one folder, and delete the Processing folder there. Also delete the folder to which you unzipped Processing in the first place (which will be probably be something like processing-2.1.1-windows64).
**Update**: Thanks to @DC_1996 for pointing out that the folder `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Processing` also has to be removed for a perfectly clean install.

That's all... Now simply download again, re-extract, and voila.

Note that you may be downloading and using the 3.0xa series, in which all buttons except run and play has been removed, and with which Javascript mode may not yet be compatible.

Comment: Not really, you also need to delete 'Processing' folder in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming

Comment: @DC_1996 Thanks! I had forgotten about that. Although not strictly required from the point of view of contributions and the Processing install itself, removing this is still important to completely remove Processing. I have updated my answer accordingly.